# What is the impulse response for 2D functions

Tags: image-processing, impulse-response

I study image processing and I am new to it. so my question is for example what is the impulse response for:

1. $$ y(m,n) = 3\times x(m,n)+9 $$
2. $$ y(m,n) = m^2n^2 \times x(m,n) $$
   where the $y(m,n)$ is output and $x(m,n)$ is input.
   thanks.

Comment: Are you aware what the impulse response actually is? Assume that $x[0, 0] = 1$ and $x[m,n] = 0$ for all other $m$ and $n$. Then, you can pretty straightforwardly work out what $y[m,n]$ comes out to in both of the above cases.

Comment: @JasonR You're right in principle, but these responses will not say anything general about the two systems, because neither of them is linear shift-invariant. Not sure if the OP wants to know what the (quite irrelevant) response to an impulse is or if the question is whether these systems are completely characterized by an impulse response.

Comment: @MattL.: You're correct; that's a good point for those seeking to understand the importance of impulse responses in characterizing a system.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jason R. in his comment, you can easily apply an impulse $\delta(m,n)$ (with $\delta(m,n)=1$ for $m=n=0$, and zero otherwise) to the systems and see what the output is. However, for those two examples the response to an impulse does not say much about the general behavior of the system.

There is an important class of systems called *Linear Shift Invariant* (LSI) systems which are completely characterized by their impulse responses. Linearity means that if $y_1(m,n)$ is the response to an input $x_1(m,n)$ and $y_2(m,n)$ is the response to input $x_2(m,n)$, then the response to the input $ax_1(m,n)+bx_2(m,n)$ is given by $ay_1(m,n)+by_2(m,n)$. If you check this condition you will find out that your first system is not linear.

Shift invariance means that if $y(m,n)$ is the response to $x(m,n)$ then $y(m-k,n-l)$ is the response to the input $x(m-k,n-l)$. Your second system does not satisfy this condition.

So none of the two systems is LSI and therefore neither of them can be characterized by their impulse response.